# How can I know when "clear recents" is called on Oreo and later?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-jobscheduler, application-lifecycle

So I want to know when the app swipes the app from the recents list, dismissing it:
This is the code I had regarding this on devices until 8. But a normal Service cannot start in the background. I tried using a JobScheduler, but onTaskRemoved is not being called for a JobScheduler (Neither the normal one, or the the ones that come with the Firebase JobDispatcher.

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("ClearFromRecentService", "ClearFromRecentService Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("ClearFromRecentService", "ClearFromRecentService Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "ClearFromRecentService END");
        //Code here
    }
}
```

How I start service:

```
  try {
            startService(new Intent(PSApplicationClass.this, OnClearFromRecentService.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.appendLog("Error trying to start OnClearFromRecentService: " + e.getMessage(), "E", Constants.OTHER);
        }
```

Error:

```
 OTHER Error trying to start OnClearFromRecentService: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=nl.hgrams.passenger/.services.OnClearFromRecentService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{9531e38 u10a172 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

Comment: Since Android Oreo and above all service's must run as a foreground service, so a simple solution will be to just run this as a foreground service

Comment: i am using same code to identify if app is killed by user and it seems to work fine on oreo and pie...... can you post how you are  starting service ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane made an edit

Comment: why do you want to know this? Also *Since Android Oreo and above all service's must run as a foreground service* - this is just not true

Comment: try this in manifest ........<service
            android:name=".utils.OnClearFromRecentService"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>

Comment: it is set to stopWithTask="false" it's just that I can't start it.Another edit to include error